# How to remove ugly frames when copiyng to Libreoffice from browser?

Tags: libreoffice, copy, html, paste, style

Sometimes i copy/paste text from browser to LibreOffice, and page formatting|stylings from the browser page spoil the text looking ugly, like this, for example:

[image]

Sometimes those frames|images|tables can be selected with mouse and deleted, but sometimes not.

How to delete them completely?
Vb or Python macro would be especially appreciated.

Comment: You can try Right-Clicking within a blank document and choose Paste Special then choose Unformatted Text which will do the text only. This is only a suggestion.

Comment: + for asking about macros for removing frames around objects

Comment: @Yurij Posted answer to the question.

Comment: @Terrance The frames more often non-selectable right in the text area. But i've posted my found solution.

Comment: + for navigator window

Comment: Sometimes after pasting to libreoffice I change page dimensions from default ones to A3 or even custom size to be able to select all desired/undesired objects.

Comment: @Yurij Thanks for the tip. May be helpful some day.

Answer (score 1):

That's it. It turned out that ugly frames are just OLE Objects. Yet more often nonselectable in editor text area, they can be found in Navigator and manipulated with.

Select it with the Navigator (F5, or View > Navigator > OLE Objects). It will open a list of all the OLE objects, then you may click on the one you want to select.

Then double click to select some ObjectXXXX there,

it will get selected as green angles appear at it's borders.

press Right mouse Button > OLE Object > Delete.

And it's gone!

Notice little green borders:
[image]

I'm almost there with macro to remove them! And gonna publish it. Stay tuned)